# Calculus Orthogonal Plane Equation

Tags: calculus

> Find all vectors $\langle 1, a, b \rangle$ orthogonal to $\langle 4, -8, 2 \rangle$.

I don't understand what question 49 is asking. I attached the answer key and am able to do the algebra to get the answer but I don't understand why we did what we did.

[image: QUESTION 49 ANSWER KEY]

Comment: Hint: dot product.

Answer (score 0):

A vector $u$ being orthogonal to another vector $v$ means that
$$u.v = 0$$

Now, if $u = (4,-8,2)$ and $v=(1,a,b)$

Then $u,v$ will be orthogonal when

$$u.v  = 0$$
$$\implies (4,-8,2).(1,a,b) = 0$$
$$\implies 4 -8a + 2b = 0$$